# What is SVG and how does it work?

Tags: css, svg

How does SVG in CSS work? For example in order to have gradients in IE9 I used this editor.
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

It spits out some code for IE9 which uses a SVG structure. Can someone explain what this is and exactly how it works? So its not loading a file from anywhere its just using the data property of url to compile a SVG file is that what its doing.

What does `data:image/svg+xml;base64` mean?

Does it slow down the render of the page? I know that PIE slows it down quite a bit so just wondering the value of this for IE9 instead of PIE for gradients.

Comment: SVG is a XML dialect to describe images, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG). `data:...` is a [data URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Url).

Comment: Googling SVG would be much quicker than posting a question.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Inherently, this site becomes a first page search result resource solely by people advising OPs to "google their question."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What that means is that you're embedding a base 64 encoded image into your css file so that your application doesn't have to make another explicit http request for the image. It's included inherently within your css file.

Comment: It's giving you an svg because ie 9 doesn't support gradients but does support svgs.

Comment: Does it take longer to render. For example PIE does take up a lot of rendering time.

Comment: Also does it load on other browsers or only is supported on IE9. The reason I ask is I don't need it to happen on IE8 or IE7 if I add it to a class with IE7 IE8 specific gradient styling using filter will it not load on those pages.

Comment: There's a good list of browsers that support svg on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svg#Support_for_SVG_in_web_browsers As far as rendering time goes there's no discernible difference as opposed to a static image on your page (just a few ms). The few ms longer it may take in rendering you'll gain back many times over in not having to make extra requests to the server for your css images. We've had great success using this approach.

Answer (score 4):

It's a data url ([link @MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs)). `image/svg+xml` says its an SVG image (and not a png or something else). Finally `base64` means that the following content is encoded using [base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa).

Answer (score 3):

You can use SVG files just like a regular jpg in your CSS. For example, `background: url(image.svg);`. That is one way to implement SVG with CSS.